# git clone fails without error on raspberry pi (raspbian jessie)

Tags: git, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I have raspbian jessie running on an raspberry pi 2, installed git 2.11 from

```
http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

installed. trying to clone any remote git repository results in the 'Cloning into ...' line being shown and then the shell prompt just returns without git actually cloning anything. No folder for the repository is created, no errors shown. --verbose doesn't give any more information either.

```
$ git clone --verbose https://github.com/url/to/repo.git
Cloning into 'repo'...
$
```

I haven't found any similar situations after googling for a while. :(

Comment: I would investigate step by step. Can you git init a new repository? Can you add and commit a file to that repo? If so, maybe you have a cached credentials problem(?). You could look at your git config content. My guess is that your problem is something to do with the "https" handling.

Answer (score 0):

Download the git source code and build it on the Raspberry Pi. The compilation is going to take a while though so be patient. Make sure you follow all the instructions listed by the git documentation, including installing the required libraries.

How to build git from source: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#_installing_from_source

Get the newest git source: https://github.com/git/git/releases

Tip: Ignore making the docs/info to save memory on your SD card (the docs is 500MB)

FYI: I ran into this exact problem on my Raspberry Pi 3 and this solved it for me.